# Download file CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I try to download uploaded files which are saved in the folder 'files' in the webroot. Here is my download function in the controller:

```
   public function download($id=null) { $this->response->file(WWW_ROOT . DS .'files'. $id ,array('download'=> true,'id'=> 'file name.pdf',
        'name'=> 'file name'));
```

And in the view I have the following:

```
   <td>  <?= $this->Html->link('Download', ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'download',$id]) ?></td>
```

First of all this results in an error under the download button (undefined variable id) and then I get the (more global) error: The requested file C:\xampp\htdocs\articles\src\C:\xampp\htdocs\articles\webroot\files was not found or not readable. I cant really understand why the part C:\xampp\htdocs\articles is repeated twice and how to fix those problems and download uploaded files (not only the specified file in the function $this->response->file but any file found by its id). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to remove `WWW_ROOT . DS .` in your file path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `file()` has `id` option also `WWW_ROOT` doen't need `DS` after it.

```
public function download($id=null) { 
    $filePath = WWW_ROOT .'files'. DS . $id;
    $this->response->file($filePath ,
        array('download'=> true, 'name'=> 'file name'));
}
```

Path are repeated because your file path was wrong and `file()` is prepending `APP` to the path you are providing.

> If the path is not an absolute path that resolves to a file, APP will be prepended to the path.

[source](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Network.Response.html#_file)

Comment: Hi, Is Easy read doc CakePHP 3 Example "Sending Files" https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files

Answer (score 12):

```
public function file_download()
{
    $file_path = WWW_ROOT.'uploads'.DS.'file_name.doc';
    $this->response->file($file_path, array(
        'download' => true,
        'name' => 'file_name.ppt',
    ));
    return $this->response;
}
```

Comment: oic, so the `return $this->response` is important, got it!